# Run Rscript interactive (readline()) in Command-line

Tags: r

I use R scripts quite often. Until now I used them right in RStudio. Now I wish to pass a script to a friend and it should be as easy as possible.

The command `Rscript` which you can simply use in cmd.exe is pretty nice and simple. But sometimes I need some additional information. I the Script I just can ask with `readline()` for an user input. But this only work if when I `source()` the file in R, but not in the command line with `Script` because this is not interactive. Is there an other command instead of Script or an option so you can run the script interactive from the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of asking, you can pass arguments, parameters, to the script.
Instead of
scrpt.R:

```
r=readline(prompt="number: ")
print(sqrt(r))
```

You can do
scrpt.R:

```
args<-commandArgs(TRUE)
print(sqrt(as.numeric(args[1])))
```

And at the command window,

```
c:\R\ax>Rscript scrpt.R 2 arg2 arg3
[1] 1.414214
```